# What's the better way to configure routes in App.js in React with react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

In App.js of React, we can either:

```
<div className="App">
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route
        path="/basics"
        >
        <BasicsPage></BasicsPage>
      </Route>
      // other routes
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</div>
```

OR

```
<div className="App">
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route
        path="/basics"
        component={BasicsPage}
        >
      </Route>
      // other routes
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</div>
```

Just wondering which is the better way to write it and if there' any difference between the two? Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dev/docs/advanced-guides/migrating-5-to-6.md#upgrade-to-react-router-v51

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Route render methods](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-render-methods):

> The **recommended** method of rendering something with a `<Route>` is to use **children** elements, as shown below. There are, however, a few other methods (see [this](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-render-methods)) you can use to render something with a `<Route>`. These are provided mostly for supporting apps that were built with earlier versions of the router before hooks were introduced.

**Example:**

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/basics">
      <BasicsPage />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/foo">
      <Foo>Some children here</Foo>
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Use the above method for declaring all the routes and use [hooks](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks) (useHistory, useLocation, useParams etc.) to access the router's internal state. This style will also make it easy to switch to [React Router v6](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/). See [this](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/dev/docs/advanced-guides/migrating-5-to-6.md#upgrade-to-react-router-v51) as pointed out by @jonrsharpe in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67087200/whats-the-better-way-to-configure-routes-in-app-js-in-react-with-react-router-d/67087661#comment118582206_67087200).

Answer (score 2):

The second solution is the best mainly because it provide `matches` props to the component.

[Here is a codesandbox exemple.](https://codesandbox.io/s/display-component-forked-98p7f?file=/src/Components/Settings.js) (check the `index.js` file than contain routes)

But each solution is usefull.

If you want pass props to the `BasicPage` the first way is better to add all of props you want.

But if you have the choice, use the second solution which is more maintainable and clean for the future of your app.

If you need to provide your custom props and props given by `react-router` you can use the third solution is :

```
<Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <App matches={props} myProps={1} />} />
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on if you want/need the [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props) (`history`, `location`, and `match`) passed on to the component.

```
<div className="App">
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route
        path="/basics"
        component={BasicsPage} // <-- route props passed
      />
      <Route
        path="/basics"
      >
        <BasicsPage /> // <-- route props not passed
      </Route>
      // other routes
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</div>
```

However, if you needed to pass additional props on to a component, then the second method allows for that.

```
<div className="App">
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route
        path="/basics"
      >
        <BasicsPage myCustomProp={someValue} /> // <-- pass custom prop
      </Route>
      // other routes
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</div>
```

And if you needed the route props ***and*** to pass additional props, then use the `render` prop.

```
<div className="App">
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route
        path="/basics"
        render={routeProps => (
          <BasicsPage
            {...routeProps}          // <-- pass route props
            myCustomProp={someValue} // <-- and pass custom prop
          />
        )}
      />
      // other routes
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</div>
```