# How to pass Props and Match to React Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I can't seem to figure out how to pass both props and match to a Route Component in React.

Example code I'm trying:

```
<Route path='/shop/:id'  component={props => <ItemInfo title='Props through component' />}/>
```

So in above, I want both the `:id` match and the `title` props, for my ItemInfo to get.

In the ItemInfo.js I tried:

```
const ItemInfo = ({props, match}) => {
// some code
console.log(props.title); // error: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
console.log(match.params.id); // error: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined
}
```

How can I access both?

Comment: You explicitly pass only one prop, title, into the component. You don't pass props named props or match, so it's unclear why you expected them to be defined.

Comment: Oh I actually found on stackoverflow the same question, thanks for commenting anyways I appreciate it haha, I'm a beginner so still getting the hang of Routers

Comment: You don't need to pass the matched `id` in props. You can use hooks from react router to access the `id` in the component.

Comment: @jonrsharpe and @AjeetShah , thanks for the help I managed to solve it by doing: `<Route exact path='/shop/:id' component={() => <ItemInfo isAuthed={true} />}/>` and importing `import { useRouteMatch } from "react-router-dom";` into `ItemInfo.js` to make `ItemInfo = (props) => {}`. And then `let match =useRouteMatch('/shop/:id').url.split('/');
  match=match[match.length-1];`.

Comment: Also see [Best way to configure routes in App.js in React with react-router-dom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67087200/2873538)